# How to use router with symfony and apache

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I use the `router` with symfony dev server like this

```
app/console server:run --router="/var/www/mysite/router/router.php" 0.0.0.0:8099
```

This works fine, but how can I use that router when I use apache as server